# Please help clarify orientation:portrait behavior in CSS

Tags: html, css, media-queries

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import,

> **list-of-media-queries** is a comma-separated list of media queries
>   conditioning the application of the css rules defined in the linked
>   url. If the browser doesn't support any of these media types, it won't
>   even load the linked resource.

So what I want to know is, if I have:

```
@import url('portrait.css') screen and (orientation:portrait);
```

does this mean that *if or when* I resize the width of the web browser on my desktop PC so the width is less than the height of the web browser, the portrait.css file will override the current style?

Or does it only load the portrait.css file on page load *and* if the viewport width is *already* less than its height?

Comment: Note that it may not necessarily override the current styles if you have the current styles appearing in the same CSS file after the `@import`, since `@import` is required to appear before any rulesets. It would only override the rulesets if all the selectors in that stylesheet were more specific.

Comment: @BoltClock Yep, I got that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

That'll just make your imported css file to work on certain conditions. That's one of my favorite feature, too. For example, you have this piece of code:

```
body {
    color:green;
}
```

When you import this using the conditional media query, for example `orientation:portrait`, your style will be 'modified' so that if the orientation *is* portrait, the color will change to green.

Quoting from [csswg's documentation](http://drafts.csswg.org/mediaqueries3/#orientation) of the media query:

> The ‘orientation’ media feature is ‘portrait’ when the value of the ‘height’ media feature is greater than or equal to the value of the ‘width’ media feature. Otherwise ‘orientation’ is ‘landscape’.

A simple case is if you use a mobile browser, of course. Since the orientation is generally portrait. In the desktop, this would take effect if you resize the window, and thus changing the orientation.

An excellent example is here in [this page](http://philarcher.org/diary/2011/importrules/)

Comment: I'm still on a learning process, too. If you downvoted, please help me clarify my answer! I would be very thankful. Thanks!

Comment: I did not vote on this answer, but what I can surmise is that it doesn't address the question of whether this takes effect only on load, or it takes effect in real-time when the user adjusts the browser window size on a desktop.

Comment: Oops scratch that, I see you edited your answer shortly after it was voted on to address the question.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-orientation-styles/

```
@media all and (orientation:portrait) {  
    /* Styles for Portrait screen */  
}  
@media all and (orientation:landscape) {  
    /* Styles for Landscape screen */  
}
```

so whenever width is less than height , this shall be a portrai , eventually will load your css file , even if the original screen was initialized at landscape.